# Docutils: traverse sections?

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

How can I traverse each of the section names of a document in Sphinx?

(and where is the documentation for docutils? It is maddeningly difficult to find anything useful beyond the [Sphinx Application API](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/appapi.html#event-doctree-resolved); even looking at the [source code for docutils/nodes.py](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/nodes.py) doesn't add much help. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out through trial and error :/

```
import docutils

def doctree_resolved(app, doctree, docname):
    for section in doctree.traverse(docutils.nodes.section):
        title = section.next_node(docutils.nodes.Titular)
        if title:
            print title.astext()

def setup(app):
    app.connect('doctree-resolved', doctree_resolved)
```